# Split a Solr index 1.4

Tags: solr

I have a Solr index 1.4 whose size is more than 20 GB. I would like to split it in 2 or 3 indexes.
Lucene 3.3 has the function PKIndexSplitter but it is not working with a Solr 1.4 index.

Is it possible to split a Solr index 1.4 ?

Thanks for help
Medley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no "method" in Solr 1.4 to do that. What you need to do is make two copies of the index. In each copy, delete records. Then optimize.

Then you can do a DistributedSearch over both indexes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is is possible to deleteByQuery using a field and its value ? I would like to delete all the records whose field 'leg' is equal to 6.

Comment: @Medley: Yes that is possible. Example for you: <delete><query>leg:6</query></delete> This will then delete those documents that match this query. You send it to the /update url

Comment: Thanks. It is ok now. The both indexes are smaller and the distributed search by using 'shards' works well.

Comment: You're welcome. Mark the question as answered if it helped you. This will help you get more questions answered in the future

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a command-line utility to split up a Lucene index into shards, based on the recommended method of

`document.uniqueId.hashCode() % numShards`

You can grab it from GitHub: [Hash-Based Index Splitter](https://github.com/healthonnet/hash-based-index-splitter#readme)

See also the [Multi Pass Index Splitter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/MultiPassIndexSplitter.html), which can split up your index either sequentially (e.g. `[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]`) or round-robin (e.g. `[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]`).

Since the docs don't include the usage for the latter, here it is:

```
Usage: MultiPassIndexSplitter -out <outputDir> -num <numParts> [-seq] <inputIndex1> [<inputIndex2 ...]
    inputIndex  path to input index, multiple values are ok
    -out ouputDir   path to output directory to contain partial indexes
    -num numParts   number of parts to produce
    -seq    sequential docid-range split (default is round-robin)
```